# Get signature from a file

Tags: .net, openssl, smime

I have a php code that gets a signature for a file using such a code

```
shell_exec("openssl smime -binary -sign".
    " -certfile '".$keyPath."/WWDR.pem'".
    " -signer '".$keyPath."/passcertificate.pem'".
    " -inkey '".$keyPath."/passkey.pem'".
    " -in '".$this->workFolder."/manifest.json'".
    " -out '".$this->workFolder."/signature'".
    " -outform DER -passin pass:'$pass'");
```

I need to have a pure managed C# code that would the same? Any idea how to do this? 
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go visit the [OpenSSL docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) to see what you are doing here, which appears to be signing document using [PKCS#7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax).

While you could certainly continue to use OpenSSL and shell from .Net using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx), there are better alternatives:

- There is a managed wrapper for OpenSSL called [OpenSSL.Net](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/).
- [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) has some PKCS#7 stuff.
- .Net has the [System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6see7k14.aspx) namespace.

Perhaps someone whos more familiar with this than I can translate your OpenSSL statement verbatim.  In the meantime, search google, msdn, and stackoverflow for stuff around these.  There are plenty of samples, but it really depends on exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: Just trying to accomplish same behavior as the openssl using pure managed C# code.

Comment: Then look into System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs or BouncyCastle.

Comment: thx, after more googling found the solution  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526572/openssl-smime-in-c-sharp. Seems to work.