# Sign file using .NET OpenSSL wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, pkcs#7, x509

I was trying to copy this line

```
openssl smime -sign -signer <chain_crt_file> -in <infile> -out <outfile> -inkey <privatekey> -outform der
```

into C# However it didn't turn out to be as easy as I thought. So far I came only this point

```
OpenSSL.Core.BIO crtBio = OpenSSL.Core.BIO.File("C:/asl/chain.crt", "r");
OpenSSL.Core.BIO keyBio = OpenSSL.Core.BIO.File("C:/asl/keydec.txt", "r");
OpenSSL.X509.X509Chain crt = new OpenSSL.X509.X509Chain(crtBio);
OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA key = OpenSSL.Crypto.RSA.FromPrivateKey(keyBio);

String str = "test";
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Where (hopefully) I'm importing chain certificate and decoded private key. 
Now the thing is how to sign a file and export is as DER. 
OpenSSL.NET wrapper lacks documentation and examples I found on the internet are 'how to encrypt and decrypt messages using public/private key' which is not a case  here.

To get started I tried to sign this "test" string (as file in/out should be pretty straightfoward) but I have no clue where to start.

The thing is that I need to **sign** this string thus I will need both key and certificates chain.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is OpenSSL wrapper required? You can sign any data using x509 cert with private key and [SignedCms .Net class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yeth51c4(v=vs.110).aspx) Have you read "7.12 Signing Data Using an RSA Private Key" on http://etutorials.org ?

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Apparently wrapper was no needed as I followed your suggestion and used PKCS12 file as this is fully supported by .NET Cryptography class.  Solution I found is pretty easy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526572/openssl-smime-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> To get started I tried to sign this "test" string (as file in/out should be pretty straightfoward) but I have no clue where to start.

The OpenSSL source is probably a good place to start. OpenSSL provides the source for `smime` in `<openssl dir>/apps/smime.c`.

OpenSSL's `smime` utility just calls `PKCS7_sign` with the appropriate parameters. From around line 688:

```
else if (operation & SMIME_SIGNERS)
    {
    int i;
    /* If detached data content we only enable streaming if
     * S/MIME output format.
     */
    if (operation == SMIME_SIGN)
        {
        if (flags & PKCS7_DETACHED)
            {
            if (outformat == FORMAT_SMIME)
                flags |= PKCS7_STREAM;
            }
            else if (indef)
                flags |= PKCS7_STREAM;

           flags |= PKCS7_PARTIAL;
           p7 = PKCS7_sign(NULL, NULL, other, in, flags);
           if (!p7)
               goto end;
        }
        ...
```

With knowledge of `PKCS7_sign`, you can visit OpenSSL's docs at [`PKCS7_sign(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html). Or, you can hunt for an example.

I don't know about the wrapper you are using.

Comment: That would work but unfortunately PCKS7 object in that wrapper has no sign method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mike - do they provide the CMS wrapper? I think that's another way to skin the cat with OpenSSL.