# Generate Apple Passbook Coupon/S-MIME Signature in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, windows, passbook, wallet

I am trying to create a Apple wallet passes in my system, after reading [Different S/MIME signature between OpenSSL and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11526572) and [Apple Passbook coupons from C#](https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2015/09/21/generate-pkpass-apple-passbook-coupons-from-c/), the system can create .pkasss automatically now.

And my problem is **signature cannot create successfully in actual**. If I using iPhone and try to open the .pkpass file, it can't be open!! I find out that is the problem is coming form signature, if I using mac to create a signature in terminal, it create a 3326bytes size signature; my code only can create a 3002 bytes file, which means the signature must be miss something.

Does Mac OS X method have a big difference between Windows OS method?

Has anyone faced this problem before? Does anyone know why the signatures are different?

Does anyone know how t fix it?

---

This is my source code:

```csharp
var cert = new X509Certificate2(assetsFolder + p12File, p12Password);
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(assetsFolder, "manifest.json"));

var cont = new ContentInfo(buffer);
var cms = new SignedCms(cont, true);
var signer = new CmsSigner(cert)
{
    IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot,
    SignerIdentifierType = SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, 
};
cms.ComputeSignature(signer, true);

var myCmsMessage = cms.Encode();
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(assetsFolder, "signature"), myCmsMessage);
```

Big Thanks!!!

**----------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------**

I found the ans of signature!!!
The setting of OID and SignerIdentifierType will affert the signature
Here is my solution:

```
        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(assetsFolder, "manifest.json"));
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(assetsFolder + p12File, p12Password);
        var oid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.2");
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(oid, buffer);
        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true); 
        var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(cert);
        cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot;
        cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));
        cmsSigner.SignerIdentifierType = SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

        byte[] myCmsMessage = signedCms.Encode();
        return myCmsMessage;
```