# Create downloadable passes (*.pkpass) for Apple passbook with .Net

Tags: javascript, ios, .net, passbook, wallet

I needed to develop a website in .Net which can create event tickets that downloadable as passbook file (*.pkpass). I tried to use. Dotnet-passbook library available in Nuget. But any created passes are not open in iPhone. Have anyone faced this issue? Any other suggestions to do this task?

Comment: If you could compile the pass, it is more likely a certificate or other configuration or content problem (E.g. Missing icon file) and less likely to be the library.

Comment: thank you for comment. yes it get compile and pkpass file is created. but not working inside iphone. is it possible to not open if image etc missing ?

Comment: “Not working” is insufficient to diagnose.  What do the iPhone logs show when you try to add the pass? They should give you the reason it is failing.

Comment: :Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.cas.passbook/1212t. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.
:Failed to add pass:'Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid."UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid., NSUnderlyingError {Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified

Comment: Check that you are using the latest Apple WWDR certificate. The one bundled with the library may haveexpired in February 2016.

Comment: i downloaded the certificate from here : https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
it will expired in 2023

Comment: check that your team name and passTypeId are correctly set and match your certificate.

Comment: Thanks @PassKit. i have solve it. i have another problem. i used mvc FileContentResult. but passes not get the *.pakpass extension. 

i used bellow code :  byte[] generatedPass = generator.Generate(request);
           
             return new FileContentResult(generatedPass, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");

Answer (score 2):

I also create .pkpass using C#, you may **reference to my past question** such this 
[generate pkpass question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296896/generate-apple-passbook-coupon-s-mime-signature-in-visual-studio).

The major problem I think, should be the pass.json file format is not correct. A easy method to test the .pkpass file must be **using xcode** and create a ios simulator, drop your .pkpass file in to simulator. The xcode log will display the reason why your file is not working, hope helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is solved. it worked after using "request.CertThumbprint" instead of location referring to the certificate. thanks. so error was validating the certification in passes.

Comment: I'm not able to get `request.CertThumbprint`, can help me to fox  the same problem as you had faced `any created passes are not open in iPhone` ? I'm using below  C# code script:

```C#
 PassGenerator generator = new PassGenerator();
            PassGeneratorRequest request = new PassGeneratorRequest();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the xcode framework or apple build package, here the info.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/18/android-and-ios-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

here you can download, the visual studio full. https://www.visualstudio.com/en/downloads/

Comment: thank you for commenting. i have VS full. and this is a web development not a mobile development. i need to create passes online. eg : https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook

Comment: Oh ok, then you mean Web App?

Comment: I think, you can't inject a framework .net on a web app, because for do this u need make a preview app with this integration, and later build a function for make a new app with content mixed, ios and .net., maybe u need other answer!, good luck

Comment: webapp require a, mixed content app builder, for do this :)

Comment: look, https://books.google.com/books?id=uDFVBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA131&ots=NORPEXqyNd&dq=mixed%20.net%20and%20ios%20app&hl=es&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q=mixed%20.net%20and%20ios%20app&f=false

Comment: Ok, sorry :(    T_T .this need more than .net. this need a .cer self-signing cert. for build urapp.

Comment: yes i have all the apple certificates. certificate for pass type id and AppleWWDRCA.

Comment: But the problem is, how you do a passbok app, without xcode or apple framework?

Comment: sorry. i am not creating passbook. i am creating passes(like tickets) that readable using on apple passbook app(wallet).

Comment: Oh, sorry its ok, but i can't help you :(