# OpenSSL equivalent in C#, .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Using this command:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -aes-256-cbc -in input.txt -out output.txt -outform DER yourSslCertificate.pem
```

I can decrypt (using my private key) an encrypted file (encrypted with my public key). Is there a direct translation to this not using OpenSSL but only .Net 4.5 Framework (or lower) classes. I can use Bouncy Castle if it helps.

The private key was created using openssl:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 100000 -newkey rsa:8912 -keyout private_key.pem -out certificate.pem
```

Comment: Not all encryption algorithms were supported in Net 4.5 that is why in many applications OpenSSL was used.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526572/different-s-mime-signature-between-openssl-and-c-sharp/11671937#11671937

Answer (score 0):

The EnvelopedCms class is the built in version, especially if you want `DER` output.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;

...

ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(File.ReadAllBytes("input.txt"));
EnvelopedCms cms = new EnvelopedCms(content);
// Change the encryption algorithm to AES-256.  Not needed when decrypting.
cms.ContentEncryptionAlgorithm.Oid = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42", null);

using (X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("yourSslCertificate.pem"))
{
    cms.Encrypt(new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, cert));
}

File.WriteAllBytes("output.txt", cms.Encode());
```

Answer (score 0):

This method did the trick.

openssl smime -encrypt -aes-256-cbc -in input.txt -out output.txt -outform DER yourSslCertificate.pem

```
public static void DecryptFileWithX509PrivateCertificate(
string inputFilePath, --path to input.txt
string outputFilePath, --path to output.txt
string privateKeyFilePath --path to yourSslCertificate.pem
)
{
    byte[] encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath);
    CmsEnvelopedDataParser parser = new CmsEnvelopedDataParser(encryptedData);
    RecipientInformationStore recipients = parser.GetRecipientInfos();
    
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(File.OpenText(privateKeyFilePath));
    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();
    
    foreach (RecipientInformation recipient in recipients.GetRecipients())
    {
        byte[] decryptedData = recipient.GetContent(privateKey);
        File.WriteAllBytes(outputFilePath, decryptedData);
        break;
    }
}
```